# Cannot read cookie in Internet Explorer from PHP when script is loaded from another domain

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, cookies

Ok, this is a little complicated:

1. I set a cookie on domain `foo.com` with php:

   `header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');` 
   `setcookie("c", "value", strtotime( '+30 days' ));`
2. I call the script `<script src='http://foo.com/script.php'>` from domain `bar.com` that loads a javascript file that is output through php

   `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`
   `echo $_COOKIE['c'];`

Now, when I open `http://foo.com/script.php` in Chrome, Firefox, Edge or Internet Explorer, it will display `value`.
When I instead load the script from `bar.com`, it will also display `value` in Chrome, Edge(!) and Firefox, but in the Internet Explorer 10/11, the cookie is not set and cannot be read.

I do not understand why the cookie is not set in IE since I am loading the script from `foo.com` where the cookie was set initially. So, the script should have access to the cookie.

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: if you just output some random text, rather than the cookie contents does it work?

Comment: yes, that works. I can also do a `var_dump($_COOKIE)` which is empty in IE but shows the cookie in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Sounds like Microsoft's xss filter. Try disabling it and see if the problem goes away (not suggesting this as a solution, just a means of understanding the behaviour)

Comment: @symcbean No, still the same problem. I serve both pages from local vhosts. Could that be problem? On a side note: It's working in Edge.

Comment: What local domain names are you using to call these scripts? IIRC IE is sometimes peculiar about domain names it accepts cookies for, they need to contain at least one dot `.`, names such a `localhost` tend to cause problems in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe Wow - that was it. I had read about this problem before and intentionally set up a vhost for `script.php` that contained a `.` I didn't expect that the requesting domain needed a `.` as well, so I used `localhost` for that. Changing that to a vhost with `.` worked. Thanks! You can add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What local domain names are you using to call these scripts?

I remember that IE is sometimes peculiar about domain names it accepts cookies for, they need to contain at least one dot `.` – names such a `localhost` tend to cause problems in that regard.

Comment: Not only the **domain hosting** the cookie but also the **domain requesting** the cookie needs to contain a `.` - weird.